# How to custom the translation from ESQL to T-SQL in Entity Framework v1.0

Tags: entity-framework

As EF v1 does not support "IN", I wonder if whether there is a way to extend the entity famework, so that we could support "IN" operator in EF v1.0.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the solution provided in MSDN forums.

```
static Expression<Func<TElement, bool>> BuildContainsExpression<TElement, TValue>(
    Expression<Func<TElement, TValue>> valueSelector, IEnumerable<TValue> values)
{
    if (null == valueSelector) { throw new ArgumentNullException("valueSelector"); }
    if (null == values) { throw new ArgumentNullException("values"); }
    ParameterExpression p = valueSelector.Parameters.Single();
    // p => valueSelector(p) == values[0] || valueSelector(p) == ...
    if (!values.Any())
    {
        return e => false;
    }
    var equals = values.Select(value => (Expression)Expression.Equal(valueSelector.Body, Expression.Constant(value, typeof(TValue))));
    var body = equals.Aggregate<Expression>((accumulate, equal) => Expression.Or(accumulate, equal));
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<TElement, bool>>(body, p);
}
```

Please go through [the thread for detailed answer](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/095745fe-dcf0-4142-b684-b7e4a1ab59f0/)

Comment: This does not work for me, as it actually generates the "OR" T-SQL and it will throw StackOverflow exception if the "List" is too big (e.g. contains more than 5000 elements), as the Expression tree is too big.
What I want is to generate "IN" T-SQL as it does in EF4.